# Can I Loop json animation within index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html5-canvas, banner-ads

I'm currently working on creating HTML5 banners through Adobe After Effects and the plugin Bodymovin. I'm trying to create 3x30s animation for GoogleAds -  When exporting, the animation loops infinitely - I was wondering whether there is an option to set the code to execute the loop only 3 times?

**Here's the code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="id=edge">
    <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=600">
    <script type="text/javascript">var clickTag = "";</script>                                                                    
    <style type="text/css"> 
                                                                  
#background_exit_dc {position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0; z-index: 400;}
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
</style>
    
</head>
<body>
<div id="container_dc">
        <div id="content_dc"></div>       
        <div id="myborder"></div> 
        <button id="background_exit_dc" onclick="window.open(window.clickTag)"></button>   
    </div>  
        
<body>
    
    <script src="player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="data2.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 300px; height: 600px;"  loop  autoplay></lottie-player>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can be done by giving parameter `loop` the number of cycles, in the initialization - `loop: 3`.